# Find RequestCharge when using LINQ query in CosmosClient

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb

When I use `CreateItemAsync` then I get an `ItemResponse` which allows me to access the `RequestCharge` in RU and possibly log it so I can understand exactly my usage of RU.

However, when querying with CosmosClient using LINQ, I do not see any way to get the RequestCharge. Seeing the RequestCharge is very useful but it seems wrong that it is only available if I query in a certain way, so I think I must be missing something.

Here is my code sample.

```
var tenantContainer = cosmos.GetContainer("myapp", "tenant");
var query = tenantContainer.GetItemLinqQueryable<Tenant>(true, null, 
    new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey("all") })
    .Where(r => r.AccountId = "1234");

var tenants = query.ToList();
//track.Metric("GetTenants", cosmosResponse.RequestCharge);
```

Note that I am using the "new" `CosmosClient` and not the old `DocumentClient`.

Comment: I havent' tried this, but if you do `ToFeedIterator()` on the query you can call `ReadNextAsync()` while there are more results and that gives you a `ResponseMessage` and that has a `Headers` property that contains `x-ms-request-charge`. Simple right?

Comment: Yes, that worked! Do you want to post an answer? Then I'll elaborate with the solution in code as part of the question?

Comment: Just a hint that you must include "using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq" before "ToFeedIterator" appears.

Comment: You can answer and accept your own question, I'm just glad it worked. I will probably use this as reference myself.

Comment: Thanks @Crowcoder - I put an answer below and I hope it will be clear to anyone else seeking a solution for the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you include this using statement.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Linq;
```

Then you can use `.ToFeedIterator()` which contains a property with `RequestCharge`.

Here is the complete code sample:

```
var container = _cosmos.GetContainer("mydb", "user");

// Normal linq query
var query = container.GetItemLinqQueryable<Shared.Models.User>(true, null,
    new QueryRequestOptions { PartitionKey = new PartitionKey(tenantName) })
    .Where(r => r.Email == loginRequest.Email);

// Instead of getting the result, first convert to feed iterator
var iterator = query.ToFeedIterator();

// And finally execute with this command that also supports paging
var cosmosResponse = await iterator.ReadNextAsync();

// And then the RequestCharge is readily available
_track.Metric("GetUserForAuthentication", cosmosResponse.RequestCharge);

// And whatever linq execution you wanted to do, you can do on the response
var user = cosmosResponse.FirstOrDefault();
```